# Webmin and SPF records

Tags: dns, dns-servers, webmin

I'm using VPS server with ubuntu and webmin. And in one of my domain
I'd like to use google apps, but neither in webmin panel nor in conf file
I see a place to add this google spf :

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a TXT record and set it to that value.

Webmin help page: http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/BINDDNSServer#Record_types

Answer (score 0):

In webmin you go to your master zone (in BIND DNS Server) and set it under Sender Permitted From records.

Comment: If another answer is incorrect, please comment on that answer as to why it is incorrect.  I edited this answer to remove the part trash talking another answer.

Comment: (...although you need at least 50 rep in order to leave a comment on someone else's question.)

Comment: Could please tell me what fields should I fill in webmin?